# How to add values of weekend and holiday's to the previous working day

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have to add weekend and holiday's value to the previous working day value so that weekend and holiday's should not display in the report but if we don't have previous working day we should simply skip the row as `2018-01-01` skipped in the below output

```
**DAYS      VALUE** 
2018-01-01  10  Holiday-1
2018-01-02  20  
2018-01-03  30  
2018-01-04  40  
2018-01-05  50  
2018-01-06  60  Saturday
2018-01-07  70  Sunday
2018-01-08  80  
2018-01-09  90  
2018-01-10  100 Holiday-2
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2018-01-02  20  
2018-01-03  30  
2018-01-04  40  
2018-01-05  180 
2018-01-08  80  
2018-01-09  190
```

I am trying with `LEAD, LAG, DATEDIFF` and in other ways but not getting any solution so please guys help he with this problem.

Comment: How do you know which dates are holidays? Is this a third column in the table, where DAYS and VALUE are?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that, I have separate holiday table for that.

Answer (score 1):

When there is a row in your Holidays calendar table (I will assume, that weekends are there too), you need to find the max date, prior the current one, for which there is no row in holidays table. Then group by this "real date" and sum the value. Something like this:

```
declare @t table([DAYS] date, [VALUE] int)
declare @Holidays table([DAYS] date, Note varchar(100))

insert into @t values
('2018-01-01',  10),
('2018-01-02',  20),
('2018-01-03',  30),
('2018-01-04',  40),
('2018-01-05',  50),
('2018-01-06',  60),
('2018-01-07',  70),
('2018-01-08',  80),
('2018-01-09',  90),
('2018-01-10',  100)

insert into @Holidays values
('2018-01-01',  'Holiday-1'),
('2018-01-06',  'Saturday'),
('2018-01-07',  'Sunday'),
('2018-01-10',  'Holiday-2')

;with cte as (
select 
    IIF(h1.[DAYS] is not null /* i.e. it is a holiday */,
         (select max([DAYS])
          from @t t2
          where t2.[DAYS] < t1.[DAYS] and not exists(select * from @Holidays h2 where h2.[DAYS] = t2.[DAYS])), t1.[DAYS]) as RealDate
    , t1.[VALUE]
from @t t1
left join @Holidays h1 on t1.DAYS = h1.[DAYS]
)
select
    RealDate
    , sum([VALUE]) as RealValue
from cte
where RealDate is not null
group by RealDate
```

Comment: It's working fine(+1) though I am using `TOP 1` approach as `CTE` creating problem in my query. I will share my query.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with cumulative sums (to define groups) and aggregation.  Define the groups as the number of non-holidays on or before a given day, then aggregate. This is the same value for a non-holiday followed by a holiday.

Then aggregate:

```
select max(days) as days, sum(value)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when holiday is null then 1 else 0 end) over (order by days asc) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by grp;
```

EDIT:

With a separate holidays table, you just need to add the `join`:

```
select max(days) as days, sum(value)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when h.holiday is null then 1 else 0 end) over (order by t.days asc) as grp
      from t left join
           holidays h
           on t.days = h.date
     ) t
group by grp;
```

Comment: I should go through the second query but it's returning all the sample data without any change.

Comment: @Susang . . . Arggh!  `group by grp`, not `group by days`!  Why else calculate it?